# NFC Android Host Card Emulation not working

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc, hce, lib-nfc

I’m trying to create NFC Virtual card hosting using Android HCE service. But I am not able to emulate it correctly.

I have created an android project to read Mifare Classic 1k NFC Tag data, using this data i created smart Virtual NFC Tag and Hosted that card using android HostApduService (Host card emulation).

I was able to successfully read physical NFC Tag data. Now, I’m trying to create clone of that data using Host card emulation Technology and hosting that card virtually using my android app. But when I tap that mobile device to NFC reader machine, data is not getting read on the Card Reader. When I read hosted data in other app it showing “Tag technology is NXP Mifare Plus (ISO 14443-4)” and “Technology available is isoDep and NfcA” serial number with some 08 digit (always generate random number staring with 08) “ATQA value is 0x0004” and “SAK value is 0x20”.  When I try to read physical card data then it show “Tag technology is Mifare Classic 1k (ISO 14443-3A)” and “Technology available is NfcA, MifareClassic and NdefFormatable” serial number with some 08 digit (06:9A:8F:AF) “ATQA value is 0x0004” and “SAK value is 0x08” with Memory information.

Physical card Data [Physical card scanned record image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6LFe.png)
Emulated card data [Emulated card scanned record image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7SX7.png)

I want get the same data which the physical card holds and is read through any NFC reader apps (eg. NFC Tools) but using android app using HCE. Currently the data which is read and hosted using android differs in Technology and Serial number.

Here is the code from that I have used for hosting the card from my android app.

**KHostApduService.class**

class KHostApduService : HostApduService() {

```
private val TAG = "HostApduService"

private val APDU_SELECT = byteArrayOf(
    0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
    0xA4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
    0x04.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
    0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
    0x07.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
    0xD2.toByte(),
    0x76.toByte(),
    0x00.toByte(),
    0x00.toByte(),
    0x85.toByte(),
    0x01.toByte(),
    0x01.toByte(), // NDEF Tag Application name
    0x00.toByte(), // Le field  - Maximum number of bytes expected in the data field of the response to the command
)


private val CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK = byteArrayOf(
    0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
    0xa4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
    0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
    0x0c.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
    0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
    0xe1.toByte(),
    0x03.toByte(), // file identifier of the CC file
)

private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER = byteArrayOf(
    0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
    0xb0.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
    0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
    0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
    0x0f.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
)

// In the scenario that we have done a CC read, the same byte[] match
// for ReadBinary would trigger and we don't want that in succession
private var READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false

private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE = byteArrayOf(
    0x00.toByte(), 0x11.toByte(), // CCLEN length of the CC file
    0x20.toByte(), // Mapping Version 2.0
    0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLe maximum
    0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLc maximum
    0x04.toByte(), // T field of the NDEF File Control TLV
    0x06.toByte(), // L field of the NDEF File Control TLV
    0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte(), // File Identifier of NDEF file
    0xFF.toByte(), 0xFE.toByte(), // Maximum NDEF file size of 65534 bytes
    0x00.toByte(), // Read access without any security
    0xFF.toByte(), // Write access without any security
    0x90.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), // A_OKAY
)

private val NDEF_SELECT_OK = byteArrayOf(
    0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
    0xa4.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for Select command
    0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
    0x0c.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
    0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
    0xE1.toByte(),
    0x04.toByte(), // file identifier of the NDEF file retrieved from the CC file
)

private val NDEF_READ_BINARY = byteArrayOf(
    0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
    0xb0.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
)

private val NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN = byteArrayOf(
    0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
    0xb0.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
    0x00.toByte(),
    0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1, P2), offset inside the CC file
    0x02.toByte(), // Le field
)

private val A_OKAY = byteArrayOf(
    0x90.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
    0x00.toByte(), // SW2   Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
)

private val A_ERROR = byteArrayOf(
    0x6A.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
    0x82.toByte(), // SW2   Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
)

private var NDEF_ID =
    byteArrayOf(0xE1.toByte(), 0x4.toByte())


private var NDEF_URI = NdefMessage(createUriRecord("www.google.com", NDEF_ID))
private var NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
private var NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
    BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(),
    2,
)


override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: ")

    if (intent?.hasExtra("cardIdentifier")!!) {
        val cardIdentifier = intent.getStringExtra("cardIdentifier")!!
        val recordType = intent.getStringExtra("recordType")!!
        Log.i(
            TAG,
            "onNDEF ID generated() onStart| received id  $cardIdentifier"
        )
       


        Log.i(TAG, "onNDEF ID generated() onStart| NDEF ID ${NDEF_ID.toHex()}")
        Log.i(TAG, "onNDEF ID generated() onStart| NDEF ID ${NDEF_ID.contentToString()}")
        Log.i(TAG, "onNDEF ID generated() onStart| NDEF ID $NDEF_ID")

        NDEF_URI =
            NdefMessage(createUriRecord("https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-4MP9-feCAxUq-DgGHYW3CwMQPAgJ",NDEF_ID))


        NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
        NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
            BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(),
            2,
        )
      
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand() | NDEF$NDEF_URI")

    return Service.START_STICKY
}

override fun processCommandApdu(commandApdu: ByteArray, extras: Bundle?): ByteArray {
    Log.d(TAG, "processCommandApdu: ")
    Log.i(TAG, "onNDEF ID generated() process | NDEF ID ${NDEF_ID.contentToString()}")
    //
    // The following flow is based on Appendix E "Example of Mapping Version 2.0 Command Flow"
    // in the NFC Forum specification
    //
    Log.i(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: " + commandApdu.toHex())

    //
    // First command: NDEF Tag Application select (Section 5.5.2 in NFC Forum spec)
    //
    if (APDU_SELECT.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "APDU_SELECT triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
     
        return A_OKAY
    }

    //
    // Second command: Capability Container select (Section 5.5.3 in NFC Forum spec)
    //
    if (CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
        
        return A_OKAY
    }

    //
    // Third command: ReadBinary data from CC file (Section 5.5.4 in NFC Forum spec)
    //
    if (READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER.contentEquals(commandApdu) && !READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK
    ) {
        Log.i(
            TAG,
            "READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER triggered. Our Response: " + READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE.toHex(),
        )
        READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = true

        return READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE
    }

    //
    // Fourth command: NDEF Select command (Section 5.5.5 in NFC Forum spec)
    //
    if (NDEF_SELECT_OK.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_SELECT_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
        //  GetResultBack.resultBack("NDEF_SELECT_OK incoming commandApdu: ${commandApdu.toHex()}");
        return A_OKAY
    }

    if (NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN.contentEquals(commandApdu)) {
        // Build our response
        val response = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + A_OKAY.size)
        System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, response, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
        System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, NDEF_URI_LEN.size, A_OKAY.size)

        Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

        READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
    
        return response
    }

    if (commandApdu.sliceArray(0..1).contentEquals(NDEF_READ_BINARY)) {
        val offset = commandApdu.sliceArray(2..3).toHex().toInt(16)
        val length = commandApdu.sliceArray(4..4).toHex().toInt(16)

        val fullResponse = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + NDEF_URI_BYTES.size)
        System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, fullResponse, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
        System.arraycopy(
            NDEF_URI_BYTES,
            0,
            fullResponse,
            NDEF_URI_LEN.size,
            NDEF_URI_BYTES.size,
        )

        Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Full data: " + fullResponse.toHex())
        Log.i(TAG, "READ_BINARY - OFFSET: $offset - LEN: $length")

        val slicedResponse = fullResponse.sliceArray(offset until fullResponse.size)

        // Build our response
        val realLength = if (slicedResponse.size <= length) slicedResponse.size else length
        val response = ByteArray(realLength + A_OKAY.size)

        System.arraycopy(slicedResponse, 0, response, 0, realLength)
        System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, realLength, A_OKAY.size)

        Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

        READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
      

        return response
    }

    //
    // We're doing something outside our scope
    //
    Log.wtf(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | I don't know what's going on!!!")
    //  GetResultBack.resultBack("I don't know what's going on!!! incoming commandApdu: ${commandApdu.toHex()}");

    return A_ERROR
}

override fun onDeactivated(reason: Int) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDeactivated() Fired! Reason: $reason")
}

private val HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()

private fun ByteArray.toHex(): String {
    val result = StringBuffer()

    forEach {
        val octet = it.toInt()
        val firstIndex = (octet and 0xF0).ushr(4)
        val secondIndex = octet and 0x0F
        result.append(HEX_CHARS[firstIndex])
        result.append(HEX_CHARS[secondIndex])
    }

    return result.toString()
}

fun String.hexStringToByteArray(): ByteArray {
    val result = ByteArray(length / 2)

    for (i in indices step 2) {
        val firstIndex = HEX_CHARS.indexOf(this[i])
        val secondIndex = HEX_CHARS.indexOf(this[i + 1])

        val octet = firstIndex.shl(4).or(secondIndex)
        result[i.shr(1)] = octet.toByte()
    }

    return result
}

private fun createTextRecord(language: String, text: String, id: ByteArray): NdefRecord {
    val languageBytes: ByteArray
    val textBytes: ByteArray
    try {
        languageBytes = language.toByteArray(charset("US-ASCII"))
        textBytes = text.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
        throw AssertionError(e)
    }

    val recordPayload = ByteArray(1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F) + textBytes.size)

    recordPayload[0] = (languageBytes.size and 0x03F).toByte()
    System.arraycopy(languageBytes, 0, recordPayload, 1, languageBytes.size and 0x03F)
    System.arraycopy(
        textBytes,
        0,
        recordPayload,
        1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F),
        textBytes.size,
    )

    return NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, id, recordPayload)
}

private fun createUriRecord(uri: String, id: ByteArray): NdefRecord {
    val textBytes: ByteArray
    try {

        textBytes = uri.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
        throw AssertionError(e)
    }
    val recordPayload = ByteArray(1 + textBytes.size)


    return NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_URI, id, recordPayload)
}

private fun fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(array: ByteArray, fixedSize: Int): ByteArray {
    if (array.size == fixedSize) {
        return array
    }

    val start = byteArrayOf(0x00.toByte())
    val filledArray = ByteArray(start.size + array.size)
    System.arraycopy(start, 0, filledArray, 0, start.size)
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, filledArray, start.size, array.size)
    return fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(filledArray, fixedSize)
}
```

}

**apduService.xml**

```
<aid-group android:description="@string/aiddescription"  android:category="other" >
    <aid-filter android:name="D2760000850101"/>
            <aid-filter android:name="A0000000423010"/>

            <!-- GlobalPlatform -->
            <aid-filter android:name="FF00000151000001"/>
            <!-- ISO 7816 Applet -->
            <aid-filter android:name="F276A288BCFBA69D34F31001"/>
            <!-- Joost Applet -->
            <aid-filter android:name="01020304050601"/>
            <!-- HelloApplet -->
            <aid-filter android:name="D2760001180002FF49502589C0019B01"/>
            <aid-filter android:name="F0394148148100" />

    <aid-filter android:name="F0010203040506"/>


</aid-group>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(CardEmulationXML) -->
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot emulate a Mifare Classic 1k, this is a non standard NFC Tag type.

You can only emulate a standard NFC Type 4 Tag.

And as in NFC the ID is only used to differentiate between multiple Tags that are in range to prevent Tag clash then a random ID is sufficient and is random for security purposes.

Thus you cannot do what you are trying to do.